# Why does my R script only print the last statement

Tags: r

I have this script that reads some data from a directory. I want to print the data and the output from the `getwd` function to the console. However, only the output from the last statement is printed. Why is that and how can I have all statements print to console?

Here's my function

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
getmonitor <- function(id, directory, summarize=FALSE)
{
    target <- paste(directory, id, '.csv', sep="")
    target 
    dt <- read.csv(target, header=TRUE)
    dt 
    getwd()
}

getmonitor('001', './specdata/')
```

What I was hoping for was to first see the output (from `dt`) and then the working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to wrap them explicitly in `print` statements. What happens now is that `getwd()` is returned from the function, and is printed when `getmonitor` finishes.

```
getmonitor <- function(id, directory, summarize=FALSE)
{
    target <- paste(directory, id, '.csv', sep="")
    print(target) 
    dt <- read.csv(target, header=TRUE)
    print(dt) 
    print(getwd())
    return(dt)
}

getmonitor('001', './specdata/')
```

Note that I returned `dt` as I thought that might be what you need outside the function. If you simply need to have stuff printed inside the function, you can use `return(NULL)` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the behavior of how control flows. So the function just returns only the *last* statement, irrespective of other earlier statements?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Using `return` you can force a function to return somewhere in the middle.